# Audience Network Mobile Web - facebook banners

Tags: facebook, web, banner, audience

I would like to implement banners of facebook into my **web HTML**.
the guide i worked with is:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/mobileweb/javascript
i did everythig good.
but the banner is not showing in my web html.
what can go wrong?
(i pressed the "GET HTML" from placement tag and put it with the right "placementid" and "app_id"...

(p.s) i implement the mobile android guide and it worked very good, only the web makes trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything be printed out by the **ad.error** event that you've subscribed?
Facebook Audience Network gives the reason for the ads not loaded.

In my case, the most common one is `Error 1001 - No Fill`.

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing to see the error code descriptions. It mentions `No Fill` may due to one of the following:

Error 1001 - No Fill. May be due to one or more of the following:

> - User not logged into Native Facebook App on Mobile Device
> - Limit Ad Tracking turned on (iOS)
> - Opt out of interest-based ads turned on (Android)
> - No Ad Inventory for current user
> - Your testing device must have the native Facebook application    installed.
> - Your application should attempt to make another request after 30    seconds.